# Going over a list to find which if any items repeat more than X times, then returning those items

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['2', '5', '7', '7', '5']
```

I need to be able to check if any item repeats X time in the list, and if so - which one(s). For instance, I'd like to check if any (and which) items repeat (2) times in the list above, in which case I would expect:

```
5, 7 # this can be in the form of a list, strings, or anything else.
```

**What I have tried:**

After looking over some previous posts on StackExchange, I first went ahead and used `collections-counter` (not sure if this is a good approach), like so:

```
repetition = collections.Counter(my_list)
```

What this returns is a dictionary, like so:

```
{'5': 2, '7': 2, '2': 1}
```

Now I still need to check which item(s) repeat twice. After some more searching, I ended up with this:

```
def any(dict):
    repeating = []
    for element in dict.values():
        if element == 2:
            (...)
```

I'm uncertain however of how to continue with thise code. Seems like I can only get the number of repetitions, in this  '2' (ie. the value from the dictionary), but am unable to figure out a simple way for getting the Keys which have a value of 2.

Is there an easy way to do it? Or should I try a different approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the [*items* of the dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) so you have both the key and the value:

```
repeating = [key for key, value in repetition.items() if value >= 2]
```

I used a list comprehension here to do the looping; all keys that have a value of 2 or higher are selected.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = ['2', '5', '7', '7', '5']
>>> repetition = Counter(my_list)
>>> [key for key, value in repetition.items() if value >= 2]
['5', '7']
```

Comment: Sorry, one follow up question. If I wanted the code to return not only the key, but also the value, in a dictionary. So rather than getting `['5','7']` in your Demo, we'd be looking for `{('5':2),('7':2)]` ; is there an easy way to do it with list comprehension?

Comment: I think I got it: `repeating = {repetition[key] for key, value in repetition.items() if value >= 2}`

Comment: Ok, finally got it: `{key: value for key, value in repetition.items() if value == 2}`